# Angular Changes are not reflected until I do a hard refresh on every screen with Shift+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R after deployment

Tags: angular, deployment, angular8, web-deployment

Every time I deploy a latest changes, I need to do hard refresh the browser to get reflected updates that we made to my angular website.
But in angular by default we will be doing it with below line in package.json

"scripts": {

```
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --output-hashing all",
```

},

And we are dploying these ui bits using bat file to azure iis server. Can some one through insights on this issue like how can get rid of hard refresh issue ?

Thanks, Anil KN

Comment: in our project we add gulp for making version.json file in assets. every n time angular check current version (from env.ts) eq version from version.json, so if not eq - user saw refresh modal with text about new version. Check files names in build, them must have cache

Comment: Thanks @Никита Середа , My code base was on Angular8. As mentioned  above , that build property should be taking care by default but its not from angular end.